# What is an intuitive name for a date column that displays events that are either in progress or completed?

Tags: dates, column-headers, intuitive

I have a table of data that I need to display to my users that contains events that are either in progress or completed. My problem is that the names that have been suggested for this column header are either too obvious (like "Date") or too wordy (like "Last Accessed/Completed" or "Date Saved/Submitted"). What, if any, are your suggestions for names for this type of column?

Answer (score 2):

Processing Date, or perhaps Process Date?

"Last Active" might also work.

I'm assuming you have another column indicating completeness?

Comment: Correct. There is a Status column to indicate the different types of completeness. I like "Last Active", because it indicates that the user last took an action for _this_ thing at _this_ time. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

*Last edit* and *Updated* are the shortest ones I can think of.

It also depends how do you intend to display timestamp in rows bellow.
"5h 25m 31s ago", "16:44 6th of November, 2014" etc...?

If you really need to save space, your timestamp also needs to be very short.

I think if your table heading says "updated" and row bellow says "3h 50m ago" users will combine them and make sense quite well. The word 'ago' is crucial here.

Do you use other time variables in your table? Other columns which have a date/time value?
If not and your UI style allows it, you can also put an icon (like http://fontawesome.io/icon/clock-o/) and show full text on mouse hover.